# Faulty image height on website

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a row of images in the Current Books on my [website](http://csdportfolio.com), to make the images the same height, I set the image to the HTML book equal to 378 using:

```
 <img alt="HTML & CSS" height= "378" src="html.jpg">
```

Using JQuery, I set the height of the other images in the row using this:

```
 $(window).load(function() {
    $(".book-pictures").height($("#html").height()); 
    $(".book-pictures").width($("#html").width()); 

});
$(window).resize(function(){
    $(".book-pictures").height($("#html").height()); 
    $(".book-pictures").width($("#html").width()); 

});
```

The height of these images are all uniform which is good, but the HTML book image height is slightly smaller than the others. Here is the html for the row:

```
<section id="Book-Section" class="portfolio">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" id="books">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                <h2 class ="small-line">Current Books</h2>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="portfolio-item" style ="vertical-align: middle">
                            <h3>Pragmatic Programmer</h3>
                            <img alt="Pragmatic Programmer" class="img-portfolio img-responsive img-rounded book-pictures"  src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41BKx1AxQWL._SX258_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <h3>The Shellcoders Handbook</h3>
                            <img alt="The Shellcoders Handbook" class="img-portfolio img-responsive img-rounded book-pictures" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Gq-XXFYpL._SX395_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <h3>HTML & CSS </h3>
                        <div class="portfolio-item"> 
                            <img alt="HTML & CSS" height= "378" class="img-portfolio img-responsive img-rounded" id="html" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41K27gRbYmL._SX258_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg">   
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <h3>Cryptography Engineering</h3>
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <img  alt="Snowboarding Cat. Impressive." class="img-portfolio img-responsive img-rounded book-pictures" id="cat-picture" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51SEhLArm%2BL._SX258_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Could someone please help me make these images uniform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the image, that is faulty. It is the text above them. So, give something like:

```
h3 {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

This will make all the headings above in a single line and you don't need to use jQuery or JavaScript either to make the uniformness. `:)`

**Preview**

[image]

Comment: @Turtle Welcome! `:)`

Comment: I was waiting for SO to let me. It said I needed to wait 6 mins to accept an answer